# Put XMLHttprequest results into one string

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I'm trying to get my array of URL's to run through a JQuery .get function to get the site's source code into one string outside of the function. My code is below.

```
var URL = ["http://website.org", "http://anothersite.com"];

var array = URL.map(function(fetch)    {

      var get = $.get(fetch, function(sourcecode) {
           sourcecode = fetch;
      }
```

I need the **sourcecode** variable to be the combination of source code on all of the URLs in the array.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put a variable outside of the function, something like this `data` variable below and append to it with `+=`:

```
var URL = ["http://website.org", "http://anothersite.com"];
var array = URL.map(function(fetch)    {
var data = null;

var get = $.get(fetch, function(sourcecode) {
     data += fetch;
}
}
```

Comment: You are missing closing parenthesis, it will cause errors.

Comment: OP's post was missing the closing one.

Comment: Ya, but he needs a correct answer. If OP's is missing then it doesn't mean that you do the same.

Answer (score 0):

Try this like,

```
var URL = ["http://website.org", "http://anothersite.com"];
var array = $(URL).map(function(fetch) {
   var data='';
   $.ajax({
      url:fetch,
      async:false,
      success : function(d){
         data=d;
      }
   });
   return data;
}).get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using jQuery, I suppose that [jQuery.each()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) may be a better way to iterate over the array.

```js
var URL = ["http://website.org", "http://anothersite.com"];
var str = [];

$.each(URL, function(index, fetch) {
  $.get(fetch, function(sourcecode) {
    str.push(sourcecode); // if you want an array
  })
});

str.join(''); // if you want a string

console.log(str);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```